# How to get floatingLabel working in polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am new to Polymer.  When using paper-elements 0.5 I was able to get a nice floatingLabel when the field is active / when the user enters the input field.

```
0.5
<paper-input-decorator id="searchText"
  floatingLabel
  label="find an author">
  <input is="core-input" id="sInput">
</paper-input-decorator>
```

However, this is not working in the same way with 1.0.0 (paper-elements 1.0.5). Documentation mention a property `alwaysFloat` which is not working the same as 0.5 (instead they float the label all the time). I couldn't understand if this has been deprecated.  Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `<paper-input>` element. This element make that effect by default.

```
<paper-input label="your label"></paper-input>
```

[Here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input) you can find documentation about it.

Comment: I have been to that page many times but couldn't understand. Could you provide a working example?

Comment: @Bala the above code is a working example. Put it on a page, type some text and the label floats. This is the default behavior of `paper-input`. You can turn floating off by adding the `no-label-float` attribute. Add `always-float-label` if you want the label to float even if the `paper-input` is empty.

Comment: @DirkGrappendorf although it is close it is not the same as 0.5.  Here is what I meant/what I would like to achieve with 1.0 , https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-input/demo.html

Comment: @Bala so you want the label to float if the input gets the focus even if it is empty? This could be tricky because paper-input-decorator only applies the 'label-is-floating' class if the input field has some content. And currently we can't extend from custom elements, so we cannot change this behavior by overriding. It seems that you need to copy paper-input-decorator, and modify the _computeInputContentClass() function.